# Select FROM OR on PostgraSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

Trying to select data using `SELECT OR` on  PostgreSQL but it's giving this output:

```
"*ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer:*"
```

Initially, it used worked on MySQL.

```
Object search=request.getParameter("search_data");
dbase.rs = dbase.st.executeQuery("select * from patient_reg where pat_no='"+search+"' OR pat_fname='"+search+"' OR pat_tel='"+search+"'");
```

Comment: This code looks prone to SQL injections. Use prepared statements instead and you won't have integer literal syntax problems either.

Comment: One of your fields is an integer. Do a `\d patient_reg` to see which one.

Comment: @Bergi Am using Java web (jsp)

Comment: Why are you enclosing numbers in single quotes to begin with?

Comment: @ggPeti Yes I have. Its pat_no which happens to be the primary key which increments. The rest are varchar.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash  String search = request.getParameter("search_data"); didn't work. Am getting the same error

Comment: Why don't you use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` as I have already suggested in my answer?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I have changed to PreparedStatement. This is how it looks:-
dbase.pst = dbase.con.prepareStatement("select * from patient_reg where pat_no='"+search+"' OR pat_fname='"+search+"' OR pat_tel='"+search+"'");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this and it has worked

String search = request.getParameter("search_data");

dbase.pst = dbase.con.prepareStatement("select * from patient_reg where pat_no::text='"+search+"' OR pat_fname='"+search+"' OR pat_tel='"+search+"'");